# How do i get a transparent background after rotaing a png image with php?

Tags: php, rotation

So I have png image and I rotate it but i get a black background..  or if i do the color code ofr white i get white..  I tried doing this..

```
$trans = imagecolorallocatealpha(image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
imagerotate($image, $degree, $trans)
```

i have also tried..

```
$trans = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 255, 255, 255, 127);
```

Can someone help me out?

here is my code..  if i change allocatealpha to 0, 0, 255, 0 then it goes blue.  but with 0, 0, 0, 127 its still black.

```
function rotate($degrees) {
    $image = $this->image;
    imagealphablending($image, false);
    $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    imagefill($this->image, 0, 0, $color);
    $rotate = imagerotate($image, $degrees, $color);
    imagesavealpha($image, TRUE);
    $this->image = $rotate;
}
```

Comment: Does the original code use `image` instead of `$image` like here?

Comment: yea they original code uses $image

Answer (score 11):

```
$destimg = imagecreatefromjpeg("image.png");
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($destimg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($destimg, 200, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($rotatedImage, true);
imagepng($rotatedImage,"rotated.png");
```

---

As per the correct comment below, this should be:

```
$destimg = imagecreatefrompng("image.png");
$transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($destimg, 255, 255, 255, 127);
$rotatedImage = imagerotate($destimg, 200, $transColor);
imagesavealpha($rotatedImage, true);
imagepng($rotatedImage,"rotated.png");
```

Comment: "imagecreatefromjpeg("image.png")" should be "imagecreatefrompng("image.png")"

Answer (score 2):

Make sure you set `imagesavealpha` to TRUE in order to preserve transparency. http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php

`imagesavealpha($image, TRUE);`

Answer (score 0):

Have you tried this?

[imagecolortransparent](http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagecolortransparent.php)

Hope i understood your question!

Comment: @Great to hear!! Remember to check on one answer as the correct on! (Doest have to be mine but the one that most helped you out)

Comment: Yea I found it didnt actually work.  It was just a white background so it appeared that way so i still looking for an answer.  Thanks for showing me that function though!

Answer (score 0):

```
        // Turn off transparency blending (temporarily)
        imagealphablending($image, false);

        // Create a new transparent color for image
        $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);

        // Completely fill the background of the new image with allocated color.
        imagefill($image, 0, 0, $color);

        // Restore transparency blending
        imagesavealpha($image, true);
```

Comment: Ok so I lied that imagecolortransparent isnt working it just looked like that because of a white background..  I tried this way again and I know it works because i can change the background to blue and red etc etc but when I mess with the alpha channel all it does make it transparent to black.. for example if i have the allocate like this.. 0, 0, 255, 75 it just makes a darker shade of blue as if it makes the blue transparent but there is a black color behind it

Answer (score 0):

You can try this: http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/rotate_image_alpha

Answer (score 0):

```
    $info = pathinfo($pathToImage);
    $name = str_replace("." . $info['extension'], "", $info['basename']);

    $size = getimagesize($pathToImage);



    $type = isset($size['type']) ? $size['type'] : $size[2];

    // Check support of file type
    if (!(imagetypes() & $type)) {
        // Server does not support file type
        return false;
    }

    $source = self::imageCreateFrom($pathToImage, trim($info['extension'])) or notfound();
    $transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($source, 255, 255, 255, 127);

    // $transparency = imagecolorallocatealpha($source, 0, 0, 0, 127);
    $rotate = imagerotate($source, 360 - $rotate_angle, $transColor);
    //imagealphablending($rotate, false);


    imagesavealpha($rotate, TRUE);
    //imagejpeg($rotate,$pathToThumbs.DIRECTORY_SEPARATOR.$info['basename']);
    self::createImage($rotate, $pathToThumbs, $info['basename'], trim($info['extension']));

    // imagejpeg($rotate);
    imagedestroy($source);
    imagedestroy($rotate);
```

Answer (score 0):

This is what I am using, this work great for .png files with transparent backgrounds. High fives!

```
function rotate($degrees) {

    // Switch from default counter-clockwise to clockwise
    $degrees = 360 - $degrees; 

    // Get the image 
    $source =  imagecreatefrompng("images/image.png");

    // Rotate the image
    $rotated_image = imagerotate($source, $degrees, imageColorAllocateAlpha($source, 0, 0, 0, 127));

    // Save the rotated image
    imagepng($rotated_image, 'images/rotated_image.png');

}
```