# Why cant I make the background of a png transparent after rotating it with php?

Tags: php, png, transparency, gd

I tried literally all day yesterday trying to figure this out.  I rotate an image via imagerotate().  I get a black background where the image isn't covering anymore.  I have tried everything i cant think of to make that background transparent..

here is my current code..

```
   function rotate($degrees) {
       $image = $this->image;
       imagealphablending($image, false);
       $color = imagecolorallocatealpha($image, 0, 0, 0, 127);
       $rotate = imagerotate($image, $degrees, $color);
       imagecolortransparent($rotate, $color);
       imagesavealpha($image, true);
       $this->image = $rotate;
   }
```

I am really starting to get ticked off.  Can someone show me some working code?  please?

Could it be something wrong with my WAMP server and dreamweaver?  because i even tried this.. http://www.exorithm.com/algorithm/view/rotate_image_alpha and it still puts out either a black or white background..

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of yesterday's question. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148774/how-do-i-get-a-transparent-background-after-rotaing-a-png-image-with-php/4148805

Comment: and yes it is.  I know I really shouldnt have posted again but you have no idea how badly i want this code to just work already..

Comment: Please specify your PHP version.

Answer (score 1):

Try setting imagesavealpha() on your rotated image.

Currently you are running imagesavealpha() on your original image. [ eg. imagesavealpha(*$image*, true); ]

Instead you want to run imagesavealpha() on the rotated image and then set $this->image... try:

```
   ...
   $rotate = imagerotate($image, $degrees, $color);
   imagecolortransparent($rotate, $color);
   imagesavealpha($rotate, true);  // <- using $rotate instead of $image
   $this->image = $rotate;
```

}