# After rotate a image, change background

Tags: php, css

It's only done in php, after rotating original image, background of the image is in black. How to eliminate background?[image]

below is my code..

```
      $imgNames  = "upload/".$_SESSION["img"];
      $sourcea=imagecreatefromjpeg($imgNames);
      $rotatea=imagerotate($sourcea, 0,0); 
      $uniqids = uniqid();
      $rotImages = "upload/".$uniqids.".jpg";
      $uni=uniqid();
      imagejpeg($rotatea,$rotImages,$q=25);
      echo "Rotated Image: <img src='$rotImages' >";
```

Comment: since it is the source image that contains the black background, you need to change your rotate code. If you want a transparent background you cant go with .jpg since its not able to be transparent.

Comment: http://www.php.net/manual/en/function.imagefill.php

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First: *.jpg not support transparency.
Use *.png image format.

Second: Check this:
[How do i get a transparent background after rotaing a png image with php?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4148774/how-do-i-get-a-transparent-background-after-rotaing-a-png-image-with-php)

Answer (score 1):

Just use css. Being that you taged it too.

```
.rotated{
transform:rotate(45deg); 
-ms-transform:rotate(45deg); 
-webkit-transform:rotate(45deg);
/*Or whatever deg you want*/
}
```

Add that class to the image tag.

Answer (score 0):

```
Add following code 



    $imgNames  = "upload/".$_SESSION["img"];
      $sourcea=imagecreatefromjpeg($imgNames);
    $transColor = imagecolorallocatealpha($imgNames, 255, 255, 255, 127);
         $rotatea=imagerotate($sourcea, 0,$transColor); 
        imagesavealpha($rotateae, true);
     $uniqids = uniqid();
      $rotImages = "upload/".$uniqids.".png";
      $uni=uniqid();
      imagejpeg($rotatea,$rotImages,$q=25);
      echo "Rotated Image: <img src='$rotImages' >";
```

Comment: what is variable $destimg means?

Comment: Just try now .. $imgNames is $destimg

Comment: i think have to use $sourcea instead of $imgNames. it works, but another doubt is have to change transparent background. How to do?

Comment: http://www.php.net//manual/en/function.imagesavealpha.php    imagesavealpha will manage transparency.